# javascript check from input if any values are in array of forbidden words

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.  I'm using jQuery and I know the inArray function but I'm stuck.  When the user inserts some values in an input field, I want to check if any of the words entered are in an array...if they are then to remove them.  Here's what I have:

```
<input type="text" id="search"/>

$("#search").bind('enterKey', function(e){
  var search = $('#search').val();
  var check = ['on', 'a', 'the', 'of', 'in', 'if', 'an'];
  var id = $.inArray(check, search);
  if (id !== -1){
    alert ("in array");
  }else{
    alert ("not in array");
  }
});
$('#search').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    $(this).trigger("enterKey");
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4ZfD/2/)

I'm sure my if statement is wrong...please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching for the words in an array just create a regular expression to replace them:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F4ZfD/)

```
$("#search").bind('enterKey', function(e){
    var search = $('#search').val(),
        check = ['on', 'a', 'the', 'of', 'in', 'if', 'an'],
        regexp = new RegExp( '\\b' + check.join( '\\b|\\b' ) + '\\b', 'ig' );
    alert( search.replace( regexp, '' ) );
});
$('#search').keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13)
{
  $(this).trigger("enterKey");
}
});
```

Comment: You're a genius...that works perfectly.  I haven't tried to learn regular expressions yet...if you have some time, can you please explain it?  What '\\b' and all of it means?

Comment: If you look at the contents of the regular expression string then it is `\bonb|\bab|\btheb|\bofb|\binb|\bif\b|\ban\b` Looking at the elements then `\b` matches a word boundary (either the start or end of a word) and `|` means `OR` - so it matches the word boundary at the start of the word then one of the words then the word boundary at the end of the word for any of the words. The `i` flags at the end of the regular expression mean the matches ignore the case of the match and the `g` flag means it will replace all matches.

Comment: You can simplify the regular expression to: `regexp = new RegExp( '\\b(' + check.join( '|' ) + ')\\b', 'ig' );`

Comment: Also, because you are entering the regular expression as a string into the constructor of a `RegExp` object then you need to escape the `\ ` character (which is an escape character in a string) which is why you need to use the double `\\ ` in the string. (You could alternatively replace both the `check` and `regexp` variables with the single statement `regexp = /\b(on|a|the|of|in|if|an)\b/ig;` [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F4ZfD/1/)).

Comment: That makes sense to me.  Since there is a boundary \b, is there an expression that matches EXACTLY the word in the array?  Look what happens when I changed my fiddle and tried replacing the words with dashes...it looks like it's catching the beginning of THEy or ONe and not adding a dash there...So if you see what i'm trying to do is to make a string with dashes to pass along in the url...

Comment: In your updated fiddle you are replacing `\s{2,}` which will replace two or more adjacent white space characters with a dash but you say in your comment above that you are trying to replace words with dashes; which one are you trying to do? There are two options in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F4ZfD/5/).

Comment: I probably phrased myself incorrectly.  The first example is exactly what I wanted to do.  Really appreciate your help, taking the time!  Can't give out enough +1s

Comment: I hope this is the last question for you...how would I add some special characters to be replaced (like periods commas slashes...basically like \W which I guess are non word characters)? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67CeN/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You switched check and search in the inArray parameters. Check the [api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/), it indicates use `inArray(value, array)` (not array, value).

Comment: That worked...I guess I should call it a night if I missed it that simple.  Can you please suggest how to remove that indexed word if it's in there?

Comment: Instead of using inArray you could use the indexOf() method on the array.

Like:
    check.indexOf(search);

then you know that if the returned index is different from -1 you have to remove it at that index.